# SQL Select n per letter of the alphabet

Tags: sql, select, max, alphabet

I'd like to make an query such as:
select * from `somefield` order by `name`

The order will ofcourse be alphabetical and i'd like for each letter of the alphabet to be showed only 5 hits. Is this possible with the query itself or should i be using php to make queries for each letter of the alphabet?

The number of rows returned this way can only be 5 x 26 rows long max.

Comment: quel SQL?  `row_number() OVER(partition by LEFT(name,1)) xx ... WHERE xx <= 5`

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support the ANSI standard windows functions.  For this purpose, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(name, 1) order by name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```

Note:  Not all databases support `left()`, to you might need `substr(name, 1, 1)` or `substring(name, 1, 1)`.

Comment: I'm doing this in my phpmyadmin but this ain't working. Nor the left() or the substr() is working there.